# clicking on download complete notification shows “Can't open file” toast?

Tags: android, notifications, apk

First in my app I let system downloader app download an apk for me. Then I use This code to install the apk file downloaded by Android default download manager:

```
if (getFileId() == downloadId) {
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + getFileName());
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
    intent.setData(apkUri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);            
} else {
    Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}                     
}
```

This code automatically runs when download is finished and a download receiver is called. And it works well. Problem is if user clicks on the notification made by default system download manager (Download complete notification), in API >= 23, I get a "Can't open file" message, which is very annoying (For any reason user might want to click on the notification). I want user be able to install apk file when they click on the notification, which is already working at api<23. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it has to do with the way that Android 7.0 handles permissions as compared to 6.0. You need to request permissions in a different way since Android 7.0. Try to tinker with the ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() method. The message would be shown because the permission to open file is not requested with this method. Here's a little snippet to get you on the right track:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
              new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
              YourRequestCode);
}
```

Here, thisActivity is your current activity.

Comment: The download is triggered by system downloader not my app. Think of that like this: I set the default android downloader download and apk. The download complete notification is posted by Android not me. But when user taps on the notifcation, he sees "Can't open file" message!